# WiFi SD card advice

Tags: sd-card

I am looking for advice from anyone who has any experience with WiFi SD cards like ez share, flash air or eye fi, such as do they work and are any of the brands better than any others and are the apps good and still maintained? I would really like to be able to download photos from a couple of older cameras I have direct to my Android mobile/iPad. I note one of the ez share cards has a switch to turn the WiFi feature off, which sounds useful, and they also do an adapter for micro SD cards, although I've read that the max you can go up to is only 32gb.

Comment: Those SD to MicroSD adapters are passive so they support the same capacity as the reader. If the reader supports SDXC then the adapter also supports SDXC (SDXC is 64GB or more)

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/photography/comments/12ocr4u/the_wifi_sd_card_market_in_2023_is_bad/) comprehensive answer to this question on Reddit. The tl;dr is that wifi SD cards can be unreliable for many different reasons and can work very differently depending on the device they are in and that SD card readers are a better option in most situations. Ergo I have bought one of [these](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0BGNZGDTC).

Comment: Hi Jamie, the links will disappear one day, destroying your answer.  You could post an image and/or description here.  And leave the links for reference.